# HTML table behaves inconsistently when I adjust colspan and then undo it through Developer tools in browser

Tags: html, css, html-table, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

Here is the summary of the code which is relevant to the issue:

```html
<table class="container-table100">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrap-table100">
        <table cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <colgroup width="278"></colgroup>
        <colgroup width="558"></colgroup>
        <colgroup width="119"></colgroup>
        <colgroup width="130"></colgroup>
        <tr class="row header">
          <th height="40"><b></b></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
          <td colspan="4">
            <table cellspacing="0" border="0">
              <colgroup width="278"></colgroup>
              <colgroup width="558"></colgroup>
              <colgroup width="119"></colgroup>
              <colgroup width="130"></colgroup>
              <tr class="row">
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>    
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I expect in the header row, there should be one cell of width 278; while in the next same level row, it should be a merged cell of width 1085 (sum of 4 columns).

When I first run the code in Chrome, it does not work as expected. The header cell is almost as long as the second row cell, which are of width 895 and 1033 respectively.

Then I start adjusting the `colspan` from 4 to 2 through Developer tools, the widths of the cells in two rows become 278 and 836. After I change the `colspan` back to 4, they become 278 and 1085, which match my expected result, but inconsistent with what appears for the first run. What's cause of this? Is there a bug in Chrome?

(The `colgroup`s are supposed to be generated by Javascript with fixed width so I do not directly put the sum into the code)

Comment: I think the issue is with your structure can you make working example of your code so far?

Comment: It's really unclear what the purpose of this is. The structure doesn't make a lot of sense. Is there any missing code you've chosen not to include in an attempt to simplify the request?

Comment: Ultimately though, there are colspans where there shouldn't be and you're trying to stop table cells from doing what they were naturally intended to do which is to equally distribute the width of the table between the number of cells. If you only have one cell, then it will span the entire width. There isn't any way around that, well not in a valid and consistent way.

Comment: Are you able to post screenshots or a working HTML example in Codepen / JS Bin, for us to visually see your intended result?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/melalameze/edit?html,output

Comment: Widths of key elements have been indicated. (The output in JS Bin is slightly different with what appears when I test it offline. The width of the top header is as long as the row below, and adjusting `colspan` from 4->2->4 does not make the expected result.)